# Could Regidrago VStar use Haxorus' Dragon Dance?

Tags: pokemon

So I was just reading my cards and realized maybe I messed up but could Regidrago VStar use a Haxorus Dragon Dance to its advantage or did I miss read it?

For context
Regidrago VStar's Apex Dragon
**Choose an attack from a Dragon Pokémon in your discard pile and use it as this attack.**

Haxorus's Dragon Dance
**As long as this Haxorus is your active Pokémon, each of its attacks does 100 more damage (before applying Weakness and Resistance). You can't add more than 100 damage this way.**

I now realize I was reading the Serebii page (https://serebii.net/card/breakthrough/111.shtml) and on there it says Pokémon and not Haxorus but just curious if this work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this [compendium entry](https://compendium.pokegym.net/ruling/902/):

> Prior to the "Black & White" series, when a Pokemon refers to itself by name, interpret that card as though the text reads "this Pokemon". This has the practical effect of not including other Pokemon of the same name; if a Pokemon copies that text, it refers to itself, not the original Pokemon. Beginning with "Black & White", when a Pokemon refers to itself by name, this extends to other Pokemon of the same name; **if a Pokemon copies that text, it refers to other Pokemon of the same name**. Also, when a Pokemon refers to "this Pokemon", this has the practical effect of not including other Pokemon of the same name; if a Pokemon copies that text it refers to itself, not the original Pokemon.

(Bolding added).

So no, it would not increase Regidrago VStar’s subsequent attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Interaction between Haxorus's Dragon Dance and an attack that copies another attack has received an [official ruling](https://compendium.pokegym.net/ruling/453/) that applies here:

> **Q:** What happens if Zoroark uses its "Foul Play" attack to copy Haxorus' "Dragon Dance" attack? Would it apply to Zoroark or not (because its name is not Haxorus)?
> **A:** Zoroark's Foul Play can choose Dragon Dance, but since its name is not "Haxorus" the attack will basically have no effect. Dragon Dance specifically refers to Haxorus, so any Pokemon not named Haxorus cannot receive the damage boost.
> Source: TPCi Rules Team (2015-10-29)